# What's the meaning of the function DFLOAT in fortran IV?

Tags: fortran, precision

I need to translate fortran IV code to Matlab. 
One of the lines of the Fortran code is:

`w(J)=DFLOAT(I)`

where w is an array and I and J are indices. Is the DFLOAT function is only some sort of type conversion?

Comment: worth noting in this example with a modern (f77 even) compiler the conversion is implicit so you dont need any type conversion function

Answer (score 1):

The [`DFLOAT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gfortran/REAL.html#index-DFLOAT-1042) function (in gfortran) converts a number into double precision. I can't find a reference to it in the [Fortran IV](http://www.textfiles.com/bitsavers/pdf/ibm/140x/C24-3322-2_Fortran_IV_Language_Specifications_IBM_1401_1440_1460_Apr66.pdf) docs, but it is available as an extension function in some compilers. The standard name for this function is [`DBLE`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gfortran/DBLE.html#DBLE). The matlab equivalent is the [`double`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) function.

Comment: I'm not sure `DFLOAT` and `DBLE` were always synonymous. The first  `DFLOAT` implementations I can remember only accepted integer arguments, whereas `DBLE` could accept `FLOAT` or `COMPLEX` as well. But you are right, `DFLOAT` isn't standard and in modern compilers it just converts whatever argument is provided into double precision floating point

Comment: Actually you should use `real()` with the appropriate kind argument instead of dble, I think.

Comment: Your link to the Fortran IV docs is broken.